# jQuery Mobile - Navigating “Back” with Query String

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I am having an issue with `data-rel="back"` not storing the query string of its passed url. The query'd page initially displayed properly, but after navigating away then back using the "back" navigational element, the page breaks because all that exists in the revisited url is the hashtag, but no query string.

---

**Query'd Page:**

```
http://localhost:4400/#details?id=100007
```

**Linking HTML:**

```
first link attempt
<button onClick="user.menuButton();">Test User Link</button>

second link attempt
<a href="#user">Go To User</a>
```

**Links to Next Page via JS:**

```
document.addEventListener('menubutton', myFunction, false);

function myFunction(){
    $('body').pagecontainer('change', '#user');
}
```

---

**Next Page HTML:**

```
<section data-role="page" id="user">
    <header data-role="header">
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" data-role="button" data-icon="carat-l" data-iconpos="notext" data-rel="back"></a>
        <h1>User Information</h1>
    </header>
    <section data-role="main"></section>
</section>
```

**When clicking "back" from Next Page, it returns to Query'd Page as:**

```
http://localhost:4400/#details *<-- Query string no longer exists.*
```

Any help in resolving this "back" link issue is greatly appreciated.

Comment: cant you use --- onclick="goBack()" --- instead of -- href="javascript:void(0)" --- and add a function -- <script>
function goBack()
  {
  window.history.back()
  }
</script>  --- or do you need the void to check undefined state

Comment: @Tasos Even when linking via <a href="#user">Go To User</a>, the "back" will not work.

Comment: Try using the div tag instead of the section tag.